# SCOPE statement for Measures present in the report?

Tags: scope, ssas, mdx

I have one Measure which I am using as a denominator in calculating multiple calculated measures. The user typically drags and drops Numerator, denominator and calculation measure to view the report.

It works fine. But now I want to implement suppression rules defined by business. For example: If the calculated % is <=5 then denominator value should be shown as *.

I have used SCOPE statement to handle this. But now I have ended up defining multiple SCOPE statments for single denominator measure. The problem is, as you must have already guessed, the result of one Scope statement is clashing with other scope statements defined for same denominator measure.

For example: Even though denominator is supposed to show actual value for a particular % calculation, it supresses it with * because other % calculation in which the same denominator measure is used returns <=5 value.

My question is: Is it possible to find out, through MDX SCOPE or something like that, which measures are actually in use, or dragged and dropped by user  in report?

May be a silly question but please help. Or give me some different perspective to solve this problem.

Thanks,

Parry

Comment: You ask "Is it possible to find out which measures are actually in use" but you need to tell us at what point you wish to do this. Do you need to access this information within the MDX command itself, within a webpage that calls the cube, with a DLL that calls the cube...?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Ideally, I wish to do that in MDX itself. Bu twe do have our own reporting control which uses dll to render cube output on a webpage, so I am open for any other ideas too.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the part of your post which says "Is it possible to find out which measures are actually in use?" I suggest this trick: `SetToStr(StrToSet("Axis(1)"))`

This will get a list of items on rows (or columns) and return it as a string. In a Micrsoft environment you could use `InStr()` to search this for Measure names, and decide what to do with an `IIF()`. I hope this gives you a starting point! I have a feeling the MDX could get very long and very messy, hurting your brain.

An easier solution to the "If the calculated % is <=5 then denominator value should be shown as *" problem is to add some code to the DLL which renders the cellset on a webpage. Just detect if you're in the relevant Measure's column, then check the cell's value is <=5 and decide what to output to the user at that point. This might hurt your brain less than the MDX required.